# Terraform if statement with true or false

Tags: terraform

I need to prepare if statement. I am wondering what is the best solution for this?

```
locals {
  prod_ingress_certyficate  = "${prod_ingress_certyficate == "true" ? var.prod_cert : var.test_cert}"
}
```

Is it the correct way? If the variable is true then user prod_cert and if false then use test_cert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference `prod_ingress_certyficate` before it is defined. But, you could create a variable called `prod_ingress_certyficate` which then you use in `locals` in your condition:

```
variable "prod_cert" {
  default = "prod_cert"
}

variable "test_cert" {
  default = "test_cert"
}

variable "prod_ingress_certyficate" {
  default = true
}

locals {
  prod_ingress_certyficate  = var.prod_ingress_certyficate == true ? var.prod_cert : var.test_cert
}

output "test" {
  value = local.prod_ingress_certyficate
}
```